# How to write cucumber test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I want to write test for edit post
I write something like:

```
Given I'm on "/post/1/edit" page
```

but in this time I haven't record with ID = 1, even if I created it in previous test

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's a test database, you won't know what the id is exactly. I think you're better off to follow the edit link from the index after the post is created.

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

```
Given a post exists
When I edit that post
```

And the steps defs could be:

```
Given /^a post exists$/ do
  @post = Post.create!(:title => "...")
end

When /^I edit that post$/ do
  visit edit_post_path(@post)
end
```